# How to add a new disk to pc , install apt program to partition

Tags: apt, partitioning

How to add a new disk to pc to save data , and how to partition a hard disk area to install apt program , thanks

Comment: Ok , thanks , but how to mount a hard disk not like usb

Comment: Use commands `sudo fdisk -l` or `lsblk` to find out the disk letter of your incoming new HDD. Let us say it is `/dev/sdc`; also assume that it has a single parition i.e. there is only /dev/sdc1. Now create a mount point by the command `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/hdd`. Now mount the HDD with the command `sudo mount -v /dev/sdc1 /mnt/hdd`. If you want to make it persistant you should make an entry into `/etc/fstab` which is **UUID=<uuid> /mnt/hdd            ext4    defaults        0       2**

Comment: There are many ways; I would add an entry in the system's file-system table (/etc/fstab) where https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab maybe useful.  There are other ways (that don't involve commands, but using your existing mounts as a guide, and `sudo blkid` to grab the UUID for the correct drive/partition as @Marmayogi mentions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you do in UBUNTU:
WARNING: Be careful you select the correct hard drive, or you will delete/crash the linux/windows OS on your first hard drive.

If it's not already installed, get 'GPARTED' which will let you select your second hard drive (assuming it's been plugged in).

Select the correct hard drive in Gparted and select 'swap off' on each partition (if they have a lock icon on them. and select 'unmount' for each partition. Then select 'Delete'.
Then click the green tick icon before you go further.
Then right click and select 'New' or 'create new partition'

Click green tick.